# Python append 2D numpy array to 3D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am running into an understanding problem of numpy arrays.
I have a dataset which looks like this when read:

```
[
   [ F0, F1, F2, F3 ... F22],
   [ G0, G1, G2, G3 ... G22],
   [ H0, H1, H2, H3 ... H22],
   [ I0, I1, I2, I3 ... I22],
   [ J0, J1, J2, J3 ... J22]
]
```

And I want to transform those in "packs of three":

```
[
   [
      [ F0, F1, F2, F3 ... F22],
      [ G0, G1, G2, G3 ... G22],
      [ H0, H1, H2, H3 ... H22]
   ],
   [
      [ G0, G1, G2, G3 ... G22],
      [ H0, H1, H2, H3 ... H22],
      [ I0, I1, I2, I3 ... I22]
   ]
   ...
]
```

So far I have wrote this code:

```
data = loadtxt('./training_data/set_0.csv', delimiter=';')
batch_size=3
features=17
labels=6

trainX = np.empty((0,batch_size, features), float)
for i in range(0, len(data)-batch_size):
    row_X = data[i:i+batch_size,0:features]
    trainX = np.append(trainX, row_X)

print(trainX[0])
```

Logging the shape of row_X gives me `(3,17)` just as I wanted.
But the `trainX` variable seems to contain the flat combination of those arrays, I would have expected the shape of `trainX[0]` to be `(batch_size,features)`.

Comment: working with tensorflow/pytorch/sklearn? what you need seems to be a moving window

Comment: @sai yes with keras/tensorflow

Comment: Did you miss this from the `np.append` docs: **If `axis` is not given, both `arr` and `values` are flattened before use.**?  If you do include `axis` then the number of dimensions must match (since it just calls `np.concatenate`).  Read and reread the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

batch_size = 3


l = np.array([
   [1,2,3,4,5],
   [ 2,3,4,5,6],
   [ 3,4,5,6,7],
   [ 4,5,6,7,8],
   [ 5,6,7,8,9],
    [6,7,8,9,0],
])

output = [l[n:n+batch_size] for n in range(len(l)-batch_size+1)]
```

Output

```
[array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]),
 array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]),
 array([[3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]),
 array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a two-dimensional numpy array like the following:

```
arr = array([[7, 9, 4, 1, 0],
             [9, 5, 1, 8, 5],
             [6, 1, 9, 7, 1],
             [2, 8, 4, 8, 7],
             [1, 2, 6, 1, 8],
             [0, 2, 7, 0, 2]])
```

In order to transform this to a three-dimensional array you would use the `reshape` function:

```
arr.reshape(3, 2, -1)
```

which gives you three "batches" of two rows each.

```
array([[[7, 9, 4, 1, 0],
        [9, 5, 1, 8, 5]],

       [[6, 1, 9, 7, 1],
        [2, 8, 4, 8, 7]],

       [[1, 2, 6, 1, 8],
        [0, 2, 7, 0, 2]]])
```

The last argument `-1` tells `reshape`, to calculate the size of the third dimension, given the actual number of elements in the array and sizes of the other dimensions.